# Why are 2 rosemary plants in the same potters getting woody at a very different pace

Tags: indoors, container-gardening, herbs, rosemary

I recently bought a couple rosemary arp plants and have them in my mini indoor greenhouse. Ive been noticing that one of them is turning woody at a much faster pace whereas the other has almost all white soft stems. Im wondering what the cause of this is and if theres anything I can do to remedy it?

I recently flipped the potter around b/c the woodier one was a bit further from the light source so maybe that's it?

I have a humidifier in there set to keep it at 75% all the time and I water about once a week or so or when my little water/light sensor says the bottom half of the potter is dried out.

this is the more rapidly turning woody:
[image]

This is the second one:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not anything you're doing - looking at both plants together, it may be that the woodier one is a slightly older plant than the other. You don't say where you bought these plants, but most are grown from cuttings - it may be the woodier had its soft upper growth cut back at some point and it grew new softer growth so the plants looked a similar size, but that doesn't make it any younger. The stems at the base of the plant don't take very long to start getting woody.

You don't say where you are in the world or why you're growing them in a greenhouse, but Rosemary is a hardy plant down to 18degF, and usually makes a shrub 6 x 6 feet high and wide when planted outside. They prefer lighter, free draining soil, full sun and not too much wet.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That's helpful to know. I purchased these both from a local nursery and I had to grow then inside because I like in new Jersey in an apt with no outdoor space unfortunately. I tried cutting some of the taller branches back a bit to promote wider bushier growth so I wasn't sure if I had maybe made a mistake doing that. So at this point I should just let them grow unfettered? I was worried the woodieness might prevent it from growing bushier

Comment: No, the woodiness is normal over time- but never cut into the woody parts, they don't regenerate off the wood, but its fine to cut the softer, greener parts.

Comment: It is also possible that you have two different cultivars. This site (https://fitnesspell.com/rosemary/) list 28 different cultivars. I own Prostrate Rosemary and it has never grown very large nor did it get woody quickly.